# PHP openssl_public_encrypt causing Page Timeout/Connection Reset?

Tags: php, windows, apache, openssl, xampp

Just migrated to a new machine and having issues.

***Note: This is a Windows 7 , Apache 2.2.21, MySQL 5.5.16, php 5.3.8 setup.***

Each time I run a certain PHP script, I am faced with a "Page Load Error - The connection was reset". I know the script works before the function call with various echo statements but calling:

> openssl_public_encrypt();

I am given a page timeout.  I have added the appropriate openssl.dll PATH to my windows configuration settings (D:\xampp\php\etc) but I am still getting page timeout errors on my actual localhost machine (and the errors above).

The page returns:

> **The connection was reset**
>
> - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

The apache ssl logs show:

> [Wed Dec 07 15:13:17 2011] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
>
> [Wed Dec 07 15:13:17 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
>
> [Wed Dec 07 15:13:17 2011] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
>
> [Wed Dec 07 15:13:17 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(465): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
>
> [Wed Dec 07 15:13:17 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(420): Configuring TLS extension handling
>
> [Wed Dec 07 15:13:17 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(795): Configuring RSA server certificate
>
> [Wed Dec 07 15:13:17 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!?
>
> [Wed Dec 07 15:13:17 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(834): Configuring RSA server private key

PHPinfo() shows:

**

### openssl

**

```
OpenSSL support          |  enabled
----------------------------------------------------------
OpenSSL Library Version  |  OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
----------------------------------------------------------
OpenSSL Header Version   |  OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
```

-

Shouldn't my library and header versions match? Could this be the cause of my error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of note, this is an error found in recent versions of apache and php. The Apache version used non-compatible files. To resolve (temporarily on local machines only):

Replace the following two files in your xampp/apache/bin folder:

- libeay32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

with the files of the same name in your xampp/php folder. The issue was resolve for me immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this log entry:

> [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT
>   match server name!?

Do you still have the same error if you access the machine through its public name instead of localhost?

Comment: Good point but I did not have the same issue on my old machine with the 'same' settings. I have created several virtual host configurations so I direct to my site via https://someurl instead of https://localhost/some_foldername. This would warn about an error (this site's cert doesnt match, blah blah) but it should not be stopping the process altogether. As you can see, it does seem to continue on regardless.

Comment: I will make notes, this is a locally run development server off a Windows 7 machine WAMP setup.