# PHP openssl_sign DIES

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use openssl_sign in PHP but every time the page says:

Cannot display the page. It throws error.

if i put die("hello"); right before openssl_sign function then it displays hello but if i put right after then i get internet explorer error cannot display page, connection has been terminated or whatever the message goes...

I tried ini set and error reporting and checking loogs of php and apache and there are no nay errors.

someone have any clue or can at least explain me?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem when working with Google PHP Client Library.
Following the answer in this topic:
[PHP openssl_public_encrypt causing Page Timeout/Connection Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423799/php-openssl-public-encrypt-causing-page-timeout-connection-reset), my problem is solved.
Hoping this note will help you too.

> Replace the following two files in your xampp/apache/bin folder:
>
> - libeay32.dll
> - ssleay32.dll
>   with the files of the same name in your xampp/php folder. The issue was resolve for me immediately.