# Google Service Accounts on localhost

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps, service-accounts

I am using Google Apps for Work and have a service account to access the Drive API in PHP.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('MyApp');
$key = file_get_contents("/path/to/secure/key");
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
      "serviceaccount@myapp.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'),
      $key, 'keysecretgoeshere', 'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', "email@domain.com"
    );
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
```

This works perfectly when I upload this to my Apache server hosted externally. What's strange is I also have a local server using EasyPHP to test it locally, and as soon as I access the page, I get a "This site can't be reached. The connection was reset" error.

Is there something I'm missing as to why it's not working from localhost?
Maybe a PHP extension not installed or some cURL/openSSL issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breakpointing the code at each point, it was an issue with OpenSSL.
The solution can be found here:

[PHP openssl_sign DIES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513063/php-openssl-sign-dies)