# testing for bad versions of openssl / php installations

Tags: php, windows, apache, openssl, xampp

Related to [PHP openssl_public_encrypt causing Page Timeout/Connection Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8423799/569976) ... is there a way I can test to see if a web server will have that as a problem and issue a warning accordingly?

That link posits that the problem is due to the fact that the OpenSSL Library Version and the OpenSSL Header Version don't match, however, nothing is said definitely.

And in any event, just because they don't match doesn't necessarily mean a problem will occur. Like maybe 0.9.8 and 0.9.9 have the same API but 1.0.0 has a different one. At that point it'd be okay if the header version was 0.9.8 and the library version 0.9.9 but not if the library version was 1.0.0.

But that isn't too helpful anyway. I'd rather get the OpenSSL library version vs. the OpenSSL header version by not parsing the phpinfo output but it is unclear to me how to do this.

I could get the version by using [OpenSSL constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.constversion.php) but is that the header version or the library version? Maybe I could get it through the Apache version, voa [apache_get_version()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php), but even that's unclear to me.

Any ideas?

Thanks!;

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find out since what version(s) is the issue fixed. Only then, it will be safe to simply check both the header and library versions against those known ones.

You may need to contact the OpenSSL developers for that.